# How to modify app.json file and change sdkVersion for an expo snack?

Tags: react-native, expo

My problem is that a part of my code does not work in my snack. But the same code works when copied in another snack. When I downloaded the code for both these projects it seems the only difference is the **sdkVersion** which is specified in **app.json** file. (My snack is using  `"sdkVersion": "32.0.0"` while the snack where the code works is using `"sdkVersion": "26.0.0"`.

The app.json file is not visible when I browse to the snack link. It seems it can only be accessed when I export the file. Now I know I could run the app locally with the changed version but I would like to continue working in the snack online environment. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can change the version of expo from the right bottom of the page.[Here is a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Vz7XzCt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change the version of Expo in the snack that you have created.

In the bottom right hand corner of your web browser you can see a menu with `Expo v32.0.0`

[image]

Click that menu bring up a list, where you can select the different version of Expo that snacks support:

[image]

I would consider trying to find out why the code doesn't run on `v32.0.0` because at some point `v26.0.0` will no longer be supported as a snack.

From the official Expo blog, https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52, they plan to drop support for SDK 26 when they release SDK 33. This will mean developing locally and as a snack may become difficult.

> Dropping SDK 25, will drop SDK 26 next release We routinely drop SDK
>   versions that have low usage in order to reduce the number of versions
>   that we need to support. This release sees the end of life for SDK 25.
>   As usual, your standalone apps built with SDK 25 will continue to
>   work; however, SDK 25 projects will no longer work within the latest
>   version of Expo Client. If you want to re-run expo build, then you’ll
>   need to upgrade from SDK 25, preferably to SDK 32 so you won’t need to
>   update again for a while (and also because each Expo version is better
>   than the last!).